# Sitecore XAML UI control from Content Editor

Tags: xaml, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm currently creating a XAML popup, what I want is an imageselector (just like the one in the content editor) in the popup as a field. I located the imageselector in the code: Sitecore.Sheel.Applications.ContentEditor.Image in the Sitecore.Kernel assembly. But how  do I render this in my XAML UI popup?

I also want to do the same with the Rich Text Editor if possible.

With the data from this field I want to create programmatically an object in the master database.

Dooes anyone have any suggestions or an alternative solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XAML apps an application (like any other ASP.NET page) is constructed of controls. These controls are represented by the `<tags>` in the XAML. There is not a single control for the Image/Media library selector it is made up of a series of XAML controls such as `GridPanel` and `Scrollbox` to create each side of the dialogue.

For example:

```
<GridPanel Width="100%" Height="100%" Style="table-layout:fixed" Columns="3" GridPanel.Height="100%">

  <Scrollbox Height="100%" Class="scScrollbox scFixSize scFixSize8" Background="white" Padding="0px" GridPanel.Height="100%" GridPanel.Width="200" GridPanel.VAlign="top" Style="overflow:auto">
    <TreeviewEx ID="Treeview" DataContext="MediaDataContext" Click="SelectTreeNode" DblClick="TreeViewDblClick" ShowRoot="true" ContextMenu='Treeview.GetContextMenu("contextmenu")' Width="100%" />
  </Scrollbox>

  <VSplitter ID="MediaBrowserLeft" Target="left" />

  <Scrollbox ID="Listview" Width="100%" Height="100%" Class="scScrollbox scFixSize scFixSize8" Background="white" Padding="0px" GridPanel.Height="100%" GridPanel.Width="100%" GridPanel.VAlign="top" />

</GridPanel>
```

.. this creates a TreeViewEx in the left hand panel and a list in the right.

The RichText editor control is part of the content editor application (loading in the RAD Editor to do the rich text editing part) and, as far as I know, is not able to be included in a XAML application.

You can find out more about XAML apps on SDN and by maybe looking at the .xml files for the main sitecore applications in `<your web root>\sitecore\shell\Applications\`. The snippet I used for this example was from `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Media\MediaBrowser\MediaBrowser.xml`.

XAML applications can become quite complicated and sometimes it may be easier to add a simple web page that opens in a content-editor window rather than going down a full XAML pop-up route. Although saying that you can take advantage of the built-in UI elements in a XAML app for a more consistent user experience.

Hope this helps.